# How to use Google Scholar to search key words in abstracts

Tags: search, google-scholar

I've noticed that I can search in Google Scholar for keywords in the titles or in the full paper content, but not in the "abstract only".

Is there a workaround for doing that?

Comment: yeah, it was about abstract only. Do you know if, now with the WoS and Google Scholar cooperation, it is possible to search to the Google Scholar database through the WoS interface? The main point of using Scholar is that it covers a much wider database

Answer (score 1):

select the option "Sort by date" in google scholar. then select the Search: "abstracts" button. only searches Articles added in the last year, sorted by date.